# How to map func_closure entries to variable names?

Tags: python, python-2.x, cpython

I have a lambda object that is created in this function:

```
def add_url_rule(self, rule, endpoint=None, view_func=None, **options):
    self.record(lambda s:
        s.add_url_rule(rule, endpoint, view_func, **options))
```

Using `func_closure` of the lambda function object I can access the closure scope of the lambda function:

```
(<cell at 0x3eb89f0: str object at 0x2fb4378>,
 <cell at 0x3eb8a28: function object at 0x3cb3a28>,
 <cell at 0x3eb8a60: str object at 0x3ebd090>,
 <cell at 0x3eb8b08: dict object at 0x3016ec0>)
```

A closer look (at the `cell_contents` attribute of each `cell` object) shows me this:

```
>>> [c.cell_contents for c in func.func_closure]
['categoryDisplay',
 <function indico.web.flask.util.RHCategoryDisplay>,
 '/<categId>/',
 {}]
```

That lambda function was created by this call:

```
add_url_rule('/<categId>/', 'categoryDisplay', rh_as_view(RHCategoryDisplay))
```

As you can see, the order does not match the argument order of the function or the order in which the arguments are used inside the lambda. While I could easily find out which element is what based on its type/content, I'd like to do it in a cleaner way.

So my question is: How can I associate it with their original variable names (or at least positions in case of function arguments)?

Comment: Looks like the keyword arguments are taken first, then the positionals, then the catch-all.

Comment: Is this tested with Python 2 or 3?

Comment: I'm using Python 2.7 but it needs to support 2.6 and 2.7. I don't think there are any relevant changes between those two versions though.

Comment: Using 2.7 and a simplified version of your function, I get a different order. Interesting.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The closures are created by the `LOAD_CLOSURE` bytecode, in the same order as their bytecodes are ordered:

```
>>> dis.dis(add_url_rule)
  2           0 LOAD_FAST                0 (self)
              3 LOAD_ATTR                0 (record)
              6 LOAD_CLOSURE             0 (endpoint)
              9 LOAD_CLOSURE             1 (options)
             12 LOAD_CLOSURE             2 (rule)
             15 LOAD_CLOSURE             3 (view_func)
             18 BUILD_TUPLE              4
             21 LOAD_CONST               1 (<code object <lambda> at 0x10faec530, file "<stdin>", line 2>)
             24 MAKE_CLOSURE             0
             27 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             30 POP_TOP             
             31 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             34 RETURN_VALUE
```

so the order is determined at compile time, by [`compiler_make_closure()`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/aff0bdab358e/Python/compile.c#l1300); this function uses the `func.func_code.co_freevars` tuple as a guide, which lists the closures in the same order.

`func.func_code.co_freevars` is set when creating a code object in [`makecode`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/aff0bdab358e/Python/compile.c#l3839), and the tuple is generated from the keys of a python dictionary, so the order is otherwise arbitrary, as common for dictionaries. If you are curious, the dict is built in [`compiler_enter_scope()`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/aff0bdab358e/Python/compile.c#l463), using the [`dictbytype()` utility function](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/aff0bdab358e/Python/compile.c#l362) from all the free variables named in the compiler symbol table, itself a python dictionary.

So, the order of the closures is indeed arbitrary (hash table ordered), and you'd use the `func.func_code.co_freevars` tuple (which can be seen as a record of the order the compiler processed the dictionary keys) to attach names to the closures:

```
dict(zip(func.func_code.co_freevars, (c.cell_contents for c in func.func_closure)))
```

Comment: Be grateful if you could offer any insights to this answer (related question, python 3) - https://stackoverflow.com/a/54841357/1882064

Comment: @arcseldon on mobile right now but all I can do is check if the references I used in my answer still apply to the [master branch of Python](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Python/compile.c). I don’t expect it to have changed however.

Comment: @arcseldon a quick scan over the same functions in `compile.c` that I mentioned in my answer shows that nothing has changed; `co_freevars` lists names in the same order as the closure cells.

Comment: @arcseldon: moreover, the [`inspect.getclosurevars()` implementation](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/inspect.py#L1390-L1441) explicitly relies on this order.

Comment: Thanks v.much, really appreciate the help/clarification.

Answer (score 5):

Thanks to YHg1s in #python on Freenode I figured it out: `func_code.co_freevars` is a tuple containing the variable names of the elements in the closure.

```
>>> func.func_code.co_freevars
('endpoint', 'view_func', 'rule', 'options')
```

So creating a dict mapping names to closure values is easy:

```
>>> dict(zip(func.func_code.co_freevars,
             (c.cell_contents for c in func.func_closure)))
{'endpoint': 'categoryDisplay',
 'options': {},
 'rule': '/<categId>/',
 'view_func': <function indico.web.flask.util.RHCategoryDisplay>}
```

Comment: Ah, and here I was going to answer *why* they are in the order they are.