# How to access a FREE variable of a function from outside

Tags: python, scope, traceback, inspect, free-variable

Let's consider we have a function and an inner function like this (**which we can not change**):

```
from functools import wraps
def outer_f(some_callable):
    def inner_f(v):
        return some_callable(v) + 1
    return inner_f
```

And we only obtain a function 'func' which is the called version of outer_f which corresponds to inner_f like that:

```
>>> func = outer_f(int)
```

In such a case, the variable named 'some_callable' is the type int and if we call func with a parameter we get an answer like this:

```
>>> func('1')
2
```

I would like to access **some_callable** from outside of function when I only have **func** function instance (which means **after** **outer_f is called**).

If I am not mistaken, some_callable is a free variable of the function inner_f (func.func_code.co_freevars). How can I know that func is called with parameter int with only looking at func?

I was unable to solve the problem using inspect module or looking at attributes of the function. Methods like calling func with trace module then inspecting the stack trace or using pdb seems promising but they would be kind of ugly hacks.

This question simply reduces to access a free variable of a function's scope from outside.

So how can I know that the free variable 'some_callable' is 'int' without executing the func?

Comment: What Python version do you have available?

Comment: What is the actual problem you're trying to solve with this? Why do you need access to `func`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do:

```
import inspect
result = inspect.getclosurevars(func).nonlocals['some_callable']
```

Example:

```
>>> from functools import wraps
>>>
>>> def outer_f(some_callable):
...     def inner_f(v):
...         return some_callable(v) + 1
...     return inner_f
...
>>>
>>> func = outer_f(int)
>>>
>>> import inspect
>>> result = inspect.getclosurevars(func).nonlocals['some_callable']
>>>
>>> result
<class 'int'>
```

Comment: getclosurevars is not implemented in python 2.7 but thanks to your answer, I was able to find a solution for 2.7 right there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19416876/reflect-inspect-closed-over-variables-in-python

Sorry for not stating my python version.