# Question on multiplication in function in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to create a simple function that returns multiplier output as shown below.

The question i want to ask is when print(times3), it does not gives a value but instead it shows 
".multiplier at 0x00000236884B3558>" which I am unsure why. Is there a way to print the number instead?

Another question is since def multiplier(n) returns n*n, shouldn't it gives 5*5=25? Therefore if I were to print(times5(times3(2))), it should give me 25*81?

```
def make_multiplier_of(n):
    def multiplier(n):
        return n*n
    return multiplier

# Multiplier of 3
times3 = make_multiplier_of(3)

print(times3)

# Multiplier of 5
times5 = make_multiplier_of(5)

# Output: 81
print(times3(9)) 

# Output: 9
print(times5(3)) #shouldn't it be 25?

# Output: 16  #shouldn't it be 81 x 25?
print(times5(times3(2)))
```

updated code:

```
def make_multiplier_of(n):



   def multiplier(m):
        return m*n
    return multiplier

# Multiplier of 3
times3 = make_multiplier_of(3)


#trying to print out times3 value here but it doesnt work
times3.__closure__[0].cell_contents

[cell.cell_contents for cell in times3.__closure__]

# Multiplier of 5
times5 = make_multiplier_of(5)

# Output: 27
print(times3(9)) 

# Output: 15
print(times5(3)) #shouldn't it be 25?

# Output: 30
print(times5(times3(2)))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use different variables for the parameters of the inner and outer functions.

```
def make_multiplier_of(m):
    def multiplier(n):
        return m*n
    return multiplier
```

Your function is ignoring the argument to `make_multiplier_of()` because `n` only refers to the argument to `multiplier()`.

Comment: alright thanks, but what about the part print(times3)? Why it doesn't print any number and it shows ".multiplier at 0x00000236884B3558>" instead?

Comment: You're printing the function, not calling the function.

Comment: I see, so how do I show the number in times3? Because I always thought that printing is one way to do it which is wrong in this case

Comment: You need to use introspection functions to see the closure variable.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19416876/reflect-inspect-closed-over-variables-in-python

Comment: thanks for the link, as I am using python3.+, I went to use the cell contents and __closure__ as shown in my updated code but it doesn't work. What am I missing here?

Comment: If it's in a script, do `print(times3.__closure__[0].cell_contents)`. What you typed would work if you typed it into the REPL.