# Access parameters of decorator and of function being decorated

Tags: python, python-3.x, arguments, decorator, wrapper

```
import functools

def test_decorator(a, b, c):
    def decorator(function):
        @functools.wraps(function)
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            return function(*args, **kwargs)
        return wrapper
    return decorator

@test_decorator(a=1, b=2, c=3)
def test(d, e, f):
    return None
```

The following method will give the arguments of the function being wrapped:

```
import inspect
fn = test
list(inspect.signature(fn)._parameters)
```

Will return d, e, f

How can I also access the parameters of the decorator/wrapper `test_decorator` i.e. `a, b, c`

Comment: Inspect the decorator? Or do you mean the values, in which case that information's not available on test. What's the context, what result are you looking for and what do you want to _do_ with it?

Comment: so i need a solution which works generically, for any decorator/decorated function pair and get the parameters of the decorator (names only) attached to the decorated function.

Comment: _", so that..."_ Also note they're not "attached", they're closed over - see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/19416876/3001761.

Comment: so the decorated_function is closed over the decorator? read through the post and still struggling to find a method which returns the argument names of the decorator.

Comment: closest I've got so far is: `inspect.getsource(fn)` which returns the string: 
 `'@test_decorator(a=1, b=2, c=3)\ndef test(d, e, f):\n    return None\n'`